# How to change login redirect location if loginUrl is relative?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

If `loginurl` property of Forms Authentication is relative - `~/...`, it's added to route of current page when timeout redirect is processed. How to use another route in this case?

For example:

loginUrl property: `~/registration/login.aspx`

current url: `site.com/main/dir/page.aspx`

and when redirect is processed, `site.com/main/dir/registration/login.aspx` url is generated and it's wrong.

I want to get `site.com/main/registration/login.aspx` but now I can't.

My `web.config` contains next lines

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/registration/login.aspx" timeout="120" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RedirectToLoginPage

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirecttologinpage(v=vs.110).aspx

To answer your question i need to know if you are using Response.Redirect and if there routing rules.

How do you configure IIS? Have you got a virtual directory to "dir"? Remove it

Comment: It's redirect after session expiration and I haven't routing rules

Comment: I've updated my question. I don't use any code, it's just redirect on timeout

Comment: Oops, I mixed up registration and security in my question. But problem is that I don't know how to get proper url to redirect for.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to login page base by form authentication use below,

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="MYWEBAPP.ASPXAUTHTT" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="100000" slidingExpiration="true" />
      </authentication>
```

You can give relative url like that.